# Find the length of a succession of the same value

Tags: r, vector

I have this vector:

```
a <- c(0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,5,6)
```

I am looking for a function which tells me the length of each suite of zero

For example, it returns me `[1] 2 1 4` for the vector *a*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `rle` to obtain `lengths` and `values` of runs of identical elements in a vector. Then, it is a matter of subsetting required `lengths`

```
with(rle(a), lengths[values == 0])
#[1] 2 1 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here are some **ugly** alternatives:

```
tapply(a[a == 0], list(c(0, cumsum(head(a, -1) != tail(a, -1)))[a == 0]), length)
```

or the same idea with `table`:

```
unname(table(c(0, cumsum(head(a, -1) != tail(a, -1)))[a == 0]))
```

---

```
unlist(Filter(length, lapply(split(a, cumsum(c(0, diff(a) != 0))), function(i)
                                                                   length(i)[all(i==0)])))
```

---

```
library(data.table)
data.table(a)[, grp := rleid(a)][a == 0, .(counts = .N), by = grp][[2]][]
```

---

```
unname(table(cumsum(c(1, diff(a)) !=0 )[a == 0]))
```